# Duplicate fields in the same shapefile

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, qfield

I am creating a project with QGIS 2.18 to be exported to QField. 
The Survey form is as follow (3 columns):

- Customer name        - checked on site?  - Comment
- Water meter number   - checked on site?  - Comment
- Type of water meter  - checked on site?  - Comment
- Tariff code          - checked on site?  - Comment
- Diameter             - checked on site?  - Comment
- etc. etc.

As one can sees, there will be several fields with the same properties ("checked on site" as form value relation, "comment" as a text).

---

Is it possible to duplicate some fields structure keeping the properties (widget, length, type, etc.) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid it's not possible. But you are lucky :D ! 
Today it's the first birthday of my son.

I made a script that do what you want. Hope this will help you or anyone else.

Have a look to this :

[image]

The script is under [pull request state](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Processing/pull/77), but you can download it on [my fork](https://github.com/geodatup/QGIS-Processing/blob/master/scripts/duplicate_field.py)

or get it from this code :

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.utils import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import QVariant


##Duplicate Fied=name
##input_layer=vector
##field_to_duplicate=field input_layer
##fieldname_list=string 


layer = processing.getObject(input_layer)

pr = layer.dataProvider()

caps = pr.capabilities()

def refreshLayer():
    layer.setCacheImage( None )
    layer.dataProvider().forceReload()
    layer.triggerRepaint()
    iface.mapCanvas().refreshAllLayers()

fields = layer.pendingFields()


QVariantDict = {
    4 : QVariant.Int,
    1 : QVariant.Double,
    10 : QVariant.String,
    14 : QVariant.Date,
}

listFieldName = str(fieldname_list).split(';')

newFieldIndex = len(fields)
FieldIdx=0

for field in fields:
    if field.name() == field_to_duplicate:
        FieldIdx = fields.indexFromName(field.name()) 
        field_type = QVariantDict[field.type()]
        field_precision = field.precision()
        field_length = field.length()
        field_widget = layer.editorWidgetV2(FieldIdx)
        field_widgetConfig = layer.editorWidgetV2Config(FieldIdx)
        progress.setText("{},{},{},{}".format(str(field.name()),str(FieldIdx), str(field_widget), str(field_widgetConfig)))
    else:
        pass

for f in listFieldName:
    if f in fields:
        pass
    else :
        if caps & QgsVectorDataProvider.AddAttributes:
            modelProperties= QgsField(f, field_type, str(field_length), int(field_precision), QVariant.String )             
            res = pr.addAttributes([modelProperties])
            layer.updateFields()            
            layer.setEditorWidgetV2(newFieldIndex , field_widget)
            layer.setEditorWidgetV2Config(newFieldIndex , field_widgetConfig)
            newField_widget = layer.editorWidgetV2(newFieldIndex)
            newField_widgetConfig = layer.editorWidgetV2Config(newFieldIndex)
            progress.setText("{},{},{},{}".format(str(f),str(newFieldIndex), str(newField_widget), str(newField_widgetConfig)))
            newFieldIndex += 1


refreshLayer()
```

any improvement will be appreciate.

Comment: Happy birthday to your son :)

Comment: Thanks Hugo and happy birthday to your son ! This script could be a great improvement for newer versions of QGIS

Comment: you are welcome. the script should be open through the processing interface (get script from online source) when Qgis team will merge the fork.  The script is not compatible to the QGIS3 for now. As I now the Widget class is refactored so, we will need to adapt this script as soon as possible. Please, don't forget to mark the [answer as resolved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)